# How to fix 'script returned exit code 1' when running Powershell script through Jenkins?

Tags: powershell, jenkins

I have a Powershell script which runs some Unity unit tests. On fail, this returns code 1, which Jenkins interprets as a fail and stops the current build. How do I avoid this behavior?

NOTE: This question is almost identical to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60943751/how-to-fix-script-returned-exit-code-1-when-running-jenkins-pipeline), but that one uses bash, so I cannot apply it to my problem. In other words, how do I mimic the `set +e` behavior in Powershell? Alternatively, how do I tell Jenkins to ignore these script return codes and to continue the build anyway?

Comment: I was able to circumvent this by adding an `exit 0` clause in my script, after running the unit testing, but this seems like going around the problem, instead of solving it.

Comment: One possibility is to use `try { } catch { }` block, or to use `powershell` with `returnStatus: true` (e.g. `def retVal = powershell(script: '<your-script>, returnStatus: true)`. https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#powershell-powershell-script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how do I mimic the `set +e` behavior in Powershell

You don't have to - it's the *default* behavior in that calls to *external programs* never<sup>[1]</sup> cause execution to stop prematurely, even if they report nonzero exit codes.

> Alternatively, how do I tell Jenkins to ignore these script return codes and to continue the build anyway?

Ensuring that your script always terminates with `exit 0` is indeed the correct way to ensure that Jenkins doesn't consider the script call failed (though you'll lose the information as to whether or not the tests failed).

---

<sup>[1] It can happen *accidentally*, due to flawed behavior up to PowerShell 7.1: If you use a `2>` redirection and `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'` happens to be effect, a script-terminating error occurs when stderr output is actually received. There is also [pending RFC #277](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell-RFC/pull/277/files), which suggests introducing an *opt-in* mechanism for properly integrating external-program calls into PowerShell's error handling.</sup>

Comment: Losing the information is fine, as I write it to a file during runtime. So this solution works well, thanks!

Comment: Glad to her it, @martorad; my pleasure.